# Get clipboard data

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard, http-get

I'm trying to write a Javascript function to edit content from clipboard before pasting. Right now i got bound event 'paste' to function via JQuery.

```
$(this.elementDoc).bind('paste', function(event){
   self.OnPaste(event);
});
```

But that's not important. Now I would like to get Data from clipboard, but I can't find out how. I would be glad for every hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a toughie. If I recall correctly, IE allows access to the clipboard, but by default Firefox does not due to security issues. I had to do this for a project I was working on, and was forced to use a small SWF file that did the copying.

http://www.jeffothy.com/weblog/clipboard-copy/

Comment: As far as I can tell, this solution allows for copying TO the clipboard, but not getting FROM the clipboard.  Therefore, this is not at all a solution to the Question proposed - I don't know why it was marked so (unless the OP was confused). If I am wrong, please explain!

Answer (score 5):

The `clipboardData` can contains data in various potential formats. Its possible a program will add clipboard data in multiple formats. To look through the formats, look through `clipboardData.types`.

Often the clipboard data contains plain text, and the first type listed in `types` will be the MIME type "text/plain". If you copy text from a browser tho, you will see two types in the list: "text/plain" and "text/html". Depending on which string you pass into `getData`, you can grab the plain text, or the html. It seems that "text" is shorthand for "text/plain" and "url" is short for "text/uri-list".

```
element.addEventListener('paste', function(event) {
  var cb = event.clipboardData
  if(cb.types.indexOf("text/html") != -1) {        // contains html
    var pastedContent = cb.getData("text/html")
  } else if(cb.types.indexOf("text/html") != -1) { // contains text
    var pastedContent = cb.getData("text/html")
  } else {
    var pastedContent = cb.getData(cb.types[0])    // get whatever it has
  }

  // do something with pastedContent
})
```

For more info on how to use `clipboardData.getData`, see [the ugly spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-datatransfer-getdata).

Comment: Added a bunch of explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get it from IE or from Chrome. First it prevents the actual paste from happening, then it does a feature check and then sets the variable text to the clipboard text. With that you can manipulate the text, and then set it as the value for the input/element your pasting to, or whatever else you want to do with it.

```
//get clipboard text
event.preventDefault();
var text = null;
if (window.clipboardData) 
  text = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
else if (event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.clipboardData)
  text = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("Text");

//manipulate the text
text = '..do stuff with it..';
//set the text
$(this).val(text);
```