# jQuery get the value of CUT

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you may see in the snippet I'm able to get the value of the 
string that is PASTED in the input.
I was wondering if there's a simple way to get the value of the CUTED string.

```js
     $('#example').on("paste cut", function(e) {
          var value = '';
          if(e.type == 'paste') {
              value = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
          } else if(e.type == 'cut') {
              // How should I get the removed part of the string
          }
          $('#result').html(value);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="example" value="Some random value" style="width:80%"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: For security reasons, I don't think most browsers will allow access to the clipboard, this post offers a solution using `setTimeout()` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364617/get-the-value-of-a-textbox-during-cut-event?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Yes I can get the value of the input if I use setTimeout() but then I need to compare the strings to get the value of the cuted string. I was hoping for a simple solution.

Comment: Just an idea: Would it be an option to set a Listener to "Ctrl + C" and then when it's pressed just save the currently selected text to a variable - boom you know what got copied.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015019/keylistener-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this solution using `window.getSelection().toString()`:

```js
     $('#example').on("paste cut", function(e) {
          var value = e.type=='paste'
                    ? e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text')
                    : window.getSelection().toString();
          console.log(e.type+': '+value);
          $('#result').html(value);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="example" value="Some random value" style="width:80%"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks cars10m. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @cars10m Nice one, +1 from me.